# .length undefined only after setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, settimeout

I am trying to load the results of a GET request from the twitter api in a nodejs file held on AWS. Currently the code runs once and console.log's the feed when loading the file in the terminal but when I use setTimeout to try to refresh the results i get .length undefined.

Currently my code looks like this...

```
var Twit = require('twit');
var config = require('./config.js');
var T = new Twit(config);

var params = {
  exclude_replies: true,
  count: 20,
  include_entities: false
};

T.get('statuses/home_timeline', params, gotData);

function gotData(err, data, response) {

  var timeLine = data;
  for (var i = 0; i < timeLine.length; i++) {
var obj = timeLine[i];

console.log(obj.user.name);
  };
};

setTimeout(gotData, 10000);
```

I have reviewed other questions relating to setInterval and .length issues but I've been unable to find anything I was able to apply to this issue

Thanks for any help you can give me

Comment: You are not running the code twice, you are running the callback twice. You need to call `T.get` in the Timeout not `gotData`

Comment: When the callback for `setTimeout()` gets triggered, it will not come with `err`, `data`, and `response`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setTimeout(gotData, 10000);` invoke ***gotData*** without any parameters where as `T.get('statuses/home_timeline', params, gotData);` invoke it passing retrieved data.

Try following

```
setTimeout(function() {
    T.get('statuses/home_timeline', params, gotData);
}, 10000);
```

Comment: Thank you that has worked perfectly, I had attempted something similar from a previous answer but tried to put the whole code block inside it

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the `GET` request again after the timeout, unless the `gotdata` function is invoked without passing response data. Try something like this.

```
setTimeout(function(){
    T.get('statuses/home_timeline', params, gotData);
}, 10000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `goData()` function expects three parameters:

```
function gotData(err, data, response)
```

But you are calling it without any params in `T.get('statuses/home_timeline', params, gotData)` and `setTimeout(gotData, 10000)`, that's why you will get this exception because `data` is `undefined` in: